# System.OutOfMemoryException in 32-bit Environment

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, exception, dll, out-of-memory

I am facing System.OutofMemoryException in only 32-bit Environment for my ASP.NET and VB.NET application which rebuilt in AnyCPU platform using Visual Studio 2008. The memory usage is not high and I couldn't even view my first page due to the exception occurred after I updated the compiled DLL.

For your information, I compiled the application in AnyCPU platform in my development machine running in x64, and copy the compiled DLL to update into all the deployed application.

**I didn't make any changes to the Configuration and Platform for Compile before**. My application works perfectly in x86 previously but it started to have this exception out of a sudden.

I tried clearing the files in %temp%, but still no luck. Restarting IIS helps as a temporary solution.

Comment: Please define what is "not high".

Comment: @LexLi currently I got total of 3493MB for Memory. Normally task manager showing around 50%-60% of usage.

Comment: sounds like you are not yet familiar with Windows process model. Every process has its own memory space which then can trigger out-of-memory exceptions under certain conditions. Server wide whole memory usage does not matter much. Learn performance monitor and collect memory related counters of IIS processed.

Comment: Ya I still have many to learn on Memory Management and Windows Process. I just wondering why it previously worked perfectly but not now.

Comment: it is a live system, not a dead one. Once the cause is located, things can be answered.